# How to send and receive messages between modern computer and Commodore 64 via WiFi?

Tags: commodore-64, terminal, linux

I want to be able to connect from my Commodore 64 to a Linux Raspberry Pi.

The ideal solution would be something like ssh that allows me to use the linux machine using the c64 as a terminal but the best I could find is telnet via CCGMS on C64 and write a little python script on the raspberry side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

# Connect to the server with `telnet $HOSTNAME 5000`.

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setblocking(False)
server.bind((socket.gethostname(), 5000))
server.listen(5)

connections = []

while True:
    try:
        connection, address = server.accept()
        connection.setblocking(False)
        connections.append(connection)
    except BlockingIOError:
        pass

    for connection in connections:
        try:
            message = connection.recv(4096)
            for connection in connections:
                if "commodore".encode() in message:
                    connection.send("Hello, dear C64!\n".encode())
                elif "quit".encode() in message:
                    exit()
                else:
                    connection.send("Which is the magic word?\n".encode())
        except BlockingIOError:
            continue
        except BrokenPipeError:
            continue
```

This small example works just fine if I connect from a modern computer.
If I connect form the Commodore 64 I can read data that is sent from the Raspberry but I cannot send data from the C64 to the raspberry.
Each time I type a character the raspberry immediately asks again "Which is the magic word?"

I'd be glad to understand what am I doing wrong and/or receiving a better solution to allow the C64 to control the linux machine.

Comment: I don't think it's apropos in your situation but be aware that TELNET is not just a bare socket; there's a bunch of handshaking going on at connect time that can throw a spanner in the works on the server side.  Here are a couple of TELNET server libraries [in Python](https://github.com/jquast/telnetlib3) (BSD license) and [in C](https://github.com/seanmiddleditch/libtelnet) (Public Domain).  I can't speak for the Python one but I've used the latter and it works quite well.

Answer (score 6):

When you call

```
        message = connection.recv(4096)
```

the `recv` function returns as soon as it has *any* data available. So as soon as you press `c`, then `message` will contain `"c"`. Then when you press `o`, `message` will contain `"o"`.

You will have to collect the incoming data into your own buffer, because `recv` is not going to do that for you. Then you can test against your magic word from the collected data in your buffer.

Comment: This looks interesting, I will try in this direction and report news...
But from a modern computer the behaviour is perfect (it is able to "check" the magic word and doesn't send data every time a character is pressed.
Weird...

Comment: That's probably because the telnet client on your "modern computer" buffers the whole line you type before you press Enter and sends it all at once. Your other telnet client appears to work differently, and sends each character as it is typed.

Comment: A popular delusion is that TCP has some concept of "messages".  It does not. TCP delivers a stream of bytes.  If you want messages, you have to invent them.

Comment: UDP does "messages" (properly called *datagrams*).  You'll need to do sequencing, dropped packet detection and retransmit, etc. yourself though...

Comment: @GregHewgill
I think your answer is indeed pointing the specific problems...
Would it be possible for you to jot a possible solution, even in pseudo code?
It would help me quite a bit.
Thanks!